# Python not Working in Vim

Tags: vim, python, gvim

I have a new install of VIM from the automatic windows installer: gvim73_46.exe

I have Python 2.7 (32 bit) installed.

If I open gvim, and type:

```
:set python?
```

I get E518: Unknown option.  If I try typing:

```
:python 'hello'
```

Vim crashes.  What could be wrong?  Here are the contents of :version in case they are helpful, although python is installed, and it is using Python 2.7.  I also checked, and C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll is where it should be... I am really lost here.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going wrong?

> VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 27 2010 17:59:02)
>   MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support Included patches: 1-46
>   Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE Big version with GUI.  Features included (+)
>   or not (-):
>   +arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist 
>   +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval 
>   +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand 
>   +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape 
>   +multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +ole -osfiletype +path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo -postscript +printer 
>   -profile +python/dyn +python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline 
>   -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl/dyn -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar 
>   +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim 
>   -xterm_save +xpm_w32     system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
>        user vimrc file: "$HOME_vimrc"  2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM_vimrc"
>         user exrc file: "$HOME_exrc"   2nd user exrc file: "$VIM_exrc"   system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
>       user gvimrc file: "$HOME_gvimrc" 2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM_gvimrc"
>       system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim" Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE
>   -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl83.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.3\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python31.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl512.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=191 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby191.dll\" -DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Zi Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib
>   shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386
>   /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib
>   advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib
>   oleaut32.lib  user32.lib      /nodefaultlib:python27.lib
>   /nodefaultlib:python31.lib   e:\tcl\lib\tclstub83.lib WSock32.lib
>   e:\xpm\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'python' option, so that's why your first command does not work.  Your second command wouldn't output anything, try "`:python print 'hello'`" ...Vim shouldn't be crashing though.